# New random sentence printed for each iteration

Tags: python

Having some trouble with this one...

I am able to randomly create a sentence with this code, but now I want to iterate through to make 10 random sentences.

```
import random, pprint

#Create first list of elements
elements1 = []

#Create second list of location descriptions
prepositionList = []

#Create second list of elements (same as first)
elements2 = []

#Randomly choose one entry from each list to make into sentence.
randomSentence = (random.choice(elements1) + ' ' +  random.choice(prepositionList) + ' ' +
             random.choice(elements2))

print(randomSentence)
```

How do I make this print 10 different sentences?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Repeat the code inside a loop:

```
for i in range(<number of times to run>):
    # Put here whatever you want to be executed 10 times
```

> A loop statement allows us to execute a statement or group of statements multiple times

To read more about loops: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loops.htm

Answer (score 0):

How about a loop? Here's the way your code would look:

```
random_sentences = []
for i in range(10):
    random_sentence = (random.choice(elements1) + ' ' +
                       random.choice(prepositionList) + ' ' + random.choice(elements2))
    random_sentences.append(random_sentence)
print random_sentences
```

The way it works is that it loops ten times and each time creates a random_sentence and adds it to a list of random sentences.